# jenkins maven: shared target directory

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, directory, share

In Jenkins is there a way to share Directory between Maven builds ?

I have two java apps .. first generates .xml in target (via surefire) that the second uses to generate  a report.

Comment: Why should one app generate the surefire report of another app?

Comment: no.. the second is a custom app that uses the generrated xml

Comment: you mean between two different pipelines ?

Comment: If it is both for the same Application, maybe you want to use a multi module maven project.

Answer (score 1):

Try the `custom workspace` option within the **advanced** options in the job configuration.

Comment: how do i create Common Custom workspace  .. can u point me to some docs

Comment: You don't need to create it. You only have to chose a directory- in the local filesystem, set it as custom workspace, and Jenkins will create it if needed.

Answer (score 1):

Use [archiveArtifacts](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/core/) option in the first build and [Copy Artifacts](https://plugins.jenkins.io/copyartifact/) plugin for 2nd.

Don't share the workspace; that's a recipe for disaster.